# CakePHP Routing with pagination

Tags: cakephp, routes, pagination

This seems to have cropped up for other users but I haven't seen an answer that looks related to what I am trying to achieve.

So basically I have an admin panel for my portfolio at `/admin/portfolio/`

and when I go to the next page I get this: `/admin/portfolio/index/page:2` and `/admin/portfolio/index/page:1`

1.) How do I remove the index from the url? So it's just `/admin/portfolio/page:2`

2.) How do I make it so that `page:1` is just `/admin/portfolio/` and if someone tries to go to page 1 then it just alters the url / redirects them to just the index without the parameter. As otherwise it means I have duplicates for the first page.

As I've said earlier I have looked at some examples online but they all seem very confusing and not the same code as I have used (see below) so I'm not sure how to achieve what I am doing.

```
    <?php echo $this->Paginator->numbers(); ?>

    <?php echo $this->Paginator->prev('« Previous', null, null, array('class' => 'disabled')); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Paginator->next('Next »', null, null, array('class' => 'disabled')); ?> 

    <?php echo $this->Paginator->counter(); ?>
```

I have tried this:

```
<?php $this->Paginator->options(array('url'=>array(
'admin'=>true,
'controller' => 'portfolio', 
  'action' => 'index'))); ?>
```

But I still get the index in the url

However adding this: `Router::connect('/admin/portfolio/*',array('admin'=>true,'controller'=>'portfolio','action'=>'index'));` does get rid of the index from the url BUT this causes a second problem in that anything can be added to the url and therefore is no longer strict and showing 404's when viewing bogus pages

So I've also tried:

```
Router::connect('/admin/portfolio/:page',
                    array('admin'=>true,'controller'=>'portfolio','action'=>'index',
                    array(
                     'pass' => array('page'),
                     'page'=> '[0-9]+'
                      )));
```

But this doesn't work either because page isn't seen by the routing!

Comment: Any updates as I'm really stumped over this :/ Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest explicitly declaring your **portfolio** routes. This way, you'll not be interfering with any other controllers/actions in your application.

With that in mind, you route definitions for the portfolio part of your application would look like this:

```
/**
 * add, edit and delete actions
 */
Router::connect('/admin/portfolio/add', array(
  'controller' => 'portfolio', 'action' => 'add', 'admin' => true
));
Router::connect('/admin/portfolio/delete/:id', array(
  'controller' => 'portfolio', 'action' => 'delete', 'admin' => true), array(
    'pass' => array('id')
  )
);
Router::connect('/admin/portfolio/edit/:id', array(
  'controller' => 'portfolio', 'action' => 'edit', 'admin' => true), array(
    'pass' => array('id')
  )
);

/**
 * index action
 */
Router::connect('/admin/portfolio', array(
  'controller' => 'portfolio', 'action' => 'index', 'admin' => true, 'page' => 1
));
Router::connect('/admin/portfolio/*', array(
  'controller' => 'portfolio', 'action' => 'index', 'admin' => true), array(
    'named' =>
      array('page' => '[\d]+'),
  )
);
```

Comment: The only problem is that it means bogus urls work e.g. `/admin/portfolio/fake-url` and don't show the 404

Comment: Also page:1 still works and doesn't redirect to fix the url duplication

Comment: @Cameron You can overcome the 'bogus url' in your controller by checking that either the named param 'page' or default value 'page' are always present - if they're not, issue a 404 or Exception. Regarding your second comment, the pagination doesn't output this url. You can access it manually yes, but only you would know about it.

Comment: In your admin_index() action:    if (empty($this->request->params['named']['page']) && empty($this->request->params['page'])) {
      throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid page'));
   }

Comment: How do I do that in 1.3 ? As Requests like that are new in 2.0 right?

Comment: Also how would I make it so that if the user MANUALLY typed in the page:1 it would remove it from the url and not affect additional params like sorting etc.